SwiftData does not retrieve my inverse one-to-many Relationship
Here is my models:
import SwiftData

@Model
final public class FirstModel {
    let name: String

    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \SecondModel.parent) var children = [SecondModel]()

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

@Model
final public class SecondModel {
    let parent: FirstModel
    let name: String

    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \ThirdModel.parent) var children = [ThirdModel]()

    init(name: String, parent: FirstModel) {
        self.name = name
        self.parent = parent
    }
}

@Model
final public class ThirdModel {
    let parent: SecondModel
    let name: String

    init(name: String, parent: SecondModel) {
        self.name = name
        self.parent = parent
    }
}

Then I create my model entries:
let schema = Schema([
    FirstModel.self,
    SecondModel.self,
    ThirdModel.self
])

let container = try ModelContainer(for: schema)
let context = ModelContext(container)

let firstModel = FirstModel(name: "my first model")
let secondModel = SecondModel(name: "my second model", parent: firstModel)
let thirdModel = ThirdModel(name: "my third model", parent: secondModel)

context.insert(firstModel)
context.insert(secondModel)
context.insert(thirdModel)

try context.save()

I want to retrieve the children from my models:
print("-- Fetch Third Model")
let thirdFetchDescriptor: FetchDescriptor<ThirdModel> = FetchDescriptor<ThirdModel>(predicate: #Predicate { $0.name == "my third model" })
let thirdModels = try context.fetch(thirdFetchDescriptor)
for entry in thirdModels {
    print(">>> \(entry) - \(entry.parent) - \(entry.parent.parent)")
}

print("-- Fetch First Model")
let firstFetchDescriptor: FetchDescriptor<FirstModel> = FetchDescriptor<FirstModel>(predicate: #Predicate { $0.name == "my first model" })
let firstModels = try context.fetch(firstFetchDescriptor)
for entry in firstModels {
    print(">>> \(entry) - \(entry.children)")
    for child in entry.children {
        print("\t>>> \(child) - \(child.children)")
    }
}

... But it does not seem to work:
-- Fetch Third Model
>>> ThirdModel - SecondModel - FirstModel

-- Fetch First Model
>>> FirstModel - []

What I would expect to see:
-- Fetch First Model
>>> FirstModel - [SecondModel]
    >>> SecondModel - [ThirdModel]

I am not sure what I am doing wrong or missing...

The following worked for me:
Change the inverse properties to optional vars
var parent: FirstModel?

var parent: SecondModel?

and you should only insert one of the models. This will cause all the related models to be inserted.
context.insert(firstModel)
//context.insert(secondModel)
//context.insert(thirdModel)


Full code:
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Foo")
            .onAppear {
                do {
                    let schema = Schema([
                        FirstModel.self,
                        SecondModel.self,
                        ThirdModel.self
                    ])

                    let container = try ModelContainer(for: schema, configurations: .init(isStoredInMemoryOnly: true))
                    let context = ModelContext(container)

                    let firstModel = FirstModel(name: "my first model")
                    let secondModel = SecondModel(name: "my second model", parent: firstModel)
                    let thirdModel = ThirdModel(name: "my third model", parent: secondModel)

                    context.insert(firstModel)

                    try context.save()
                    
                    print("-- Fetch Third Model")
                    let thirdFetchDescriptor: FetchDescriptor<ThirdModel> = FetchDescriptor<ThirdModel>(predicate: #Predicate { $0.name == "my third model" })
                    let thirdModels = try context.fetch(thirdFetchDescriptor)
                    for entry in thirdModels {
                        print(">>> \(entry) - \(entry.parent!) - \(entry.parent!.parent!)")
                    }

                    print("-- Fetch First Model")
                    let firstFetchDescriptor: FetchDescriptor<FirstModel> = FetchDescriptor<FirstModel>(predicate: #Predicate { $0.name == "my first model" })
                    let firstModels = try context.fetch(firstFetchDescriptor)
                    for entry in firstModels {
                        print(">>> \(entry) - \(entry.children)")
                        for child in entry.children {
                            print("\t>>> \(child) - \(child.children)")
                        }
                    }
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
    }
}
@Model
final public class FirstModel {
    let name: String

    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \SecondModel.parent) var children = [SecondModel]()

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

@Model
final public class SecondModel {
    var parent: FirstModel?
    let name: String

    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \ThirdModel.parent) var children = [ThirdModel]()

    init(name: String, parent: FirstModel) {
        self.name = name
        self.parent = parent
    }
}

@Model
final public class ThirdModel {
    var parent: SecondModel?
    let name: String

    init(name: String, parent: SecondModel) {
        self.name = name
        self.parent = parent
    }
}


Thanks @Sweeper for your suggestion. Your solution seems to be simpler and more elegant even if it is a bit magical why it would work with your solution and not my initial solution. Anyway, I tried and it does not work for me (MacOS 14.5, Apple Swift version 5.10). It's still not able to retrieve the children of FirstModel: >>> FirstModel - []

@OlivierM It worked for me on macOS 14.1 and iOS 17.4. I added the full code. See if you can reproduce with that.

Thanks @Sweeper, you are right. Your code works.
After posting my message on SO, I modified @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \SecondModel.parent) var children = [SecondModel]() to @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \SecondModel.parent) var children: [SecondModel]?
By making the children optional, your change does not work... Anyway, I have a working solution - even it is a bit magic why it works...

I still have an issue with Swiftdata and one-to-many relation... Here is my new issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78541351/6267288 in case you see something.
I tried to duplicate the working sample you did for my first issue to look like the second issue but it does not seem to work.
