SwiftData does not retrieve my inverse one-to-many Relationship (bis)
I am having an issue to insert my model and its one-to-many children with SwiftData.
I had a similar problem few days ago solved by @Sweeper. Thanks to its answer I could fix my issue; But when trying to apply the same changes in this code. It does not work.
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

@Model
public final class MyModel : CustomStringConvertible {
    var uuid: String
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \MyModelField.model) var fields = [MyModelField]()

    init(uuid: String) {
        self.uuid = uuid
    }

    public var description: String {
        return "\(self.uuid)(\(self.fields))"
    }
}

@Model
public final class MyModelField : CustomStringConvertible {
    let key: String
    let value: String
    var model: MyModel?

    init(_ model: MyModel, _ key: String, _ value: String) {
        self.model = model
        self.key = key
        self.value = value
    }

    public var description: String {
        return "\(key):\(value)"
    }
}

@ModelActor
public actor LocalDatabaseService {
    public static let shared = LocalDatabaseService()

    let schema = Schema([ MyModel.self, MyModelField.self ])

    public init() {
        self.modelContainer = try! ModelContainer(for: self.schema)
        let context = ModelContext(modelContainer)
        self.modelExecutor = DefaultSerialModelExecutor(modelContext: context)
    }

    public func createMyModel(uuid: String) throws {
        let modelContext = self.modelContext

        let myModel = MyModel(uuid: uuid)
        let field1 = MyModelField(myModel, "hello", "world")
        let field2 = MyModelField(myModel, "bonjour", "monde")
        modelContext.insert(myModel)
        
        // Dummy print in case the garbage collector has removed non used MyModelField
        print("field1:\(field1) - field2:\(field2)")
        
        try modelContext.save()
    }

    func dumpMyModels() throws {
        let fetchDescriptor = FetchDescriptor<MyModel>()
        let myModels = try modelContext.fetch(fetchDescriptor)

        print("# Dump:\(myModels)")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Task {
            print("# List:")
            try await LocalDatabaseService.shared.dumpMyModels()

            print("# Add:")
            let id = "9C66CA5B-D91C-480F-B02C-2D14EEB49902"
            try await LocalDatabaseService.shared.createMyModel(uuid: id)

            print("# List:")
            try await LocalDatabaseService.shared.dumpMyModels()
            print("DONE")
        }
        return VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundStyle(.tint)
            Text("Hello, world!")
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

I confirm I do not see any SQL request for the MyModelField entries.
What I see:
# List:
# Dump:[]
# Add:
field1:hello:world - field2:bonjour:monde
# List:
# Dump:[9C66CA5B-D91C-480F-B02C-2D14EEB49902([])]
DONE

What I would expect:
# List:
# Dump:[]
# Add:
field1:hello:world - field2:bonjour:monde
# List:
# Dump:[9C66CA5B-D91C-480F-B02C-2D14EEB49902(["hello":"world","bonjour":"monde"])]
DONE


@JoakimDanielson the reproducible example is in the question - in the first code snippet. The output comes from there.

I found some workarounds to fix my issues. With these two workaround, I have the expected result:

Ordering of the field settings for MyModelField:

init(_ model: MyModel, _ key: String, _ value: String) {
    self.key = key
    self.value = value
    self.model = model // <---- Must be set at the end!!! It is documented somewhere?
}


The first MyModelField is inserted with ModelField while the subsequent must be inserted separatly...

let myModel = MyModel(uuid: uuid)
let field1 = MyModelField(myModel, "hello", "world")
modelContext.insert(myModel)
let field2 = MyModelField(myModel, "bonjour", "monde")
modelContext.insert(field2)

try modelContext.save()

If anyone has official documentation about these two workarounds, I will be happy to take it!

There seems to be several ways to workaround this, one way I did was to not insert myModel but both field1 and field2 and it worked (without implementing #1). Another way is to insert MyModel and then do myModel.fields.append on the fields (without inserting them) and it works. Overall there seems to be some issues with relationships in SwiftData right now.
